# Problem upgrading Centos7 to Centos8

Tags: centos, upgrade, dnf

I have a problem upgrading CentOS 7 to CentOS 8.

When I run

`sudo dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync`

I get the following errors:

```
    Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.1.1.1c.hmac from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/.libssl.so.1.1.1c.hmac from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/engines-1.1/afalg.so from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/engines-1.1/capi.so from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/engines-1.1/padlock.so from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1.1c from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1.1c from install of openssl-libs-1:1.1.1c-15.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl11-libs-1:1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpmconf/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc from install of python3-rpmconf-1.0.21-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python36-rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpmconf/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc from install of python3-rpmconf-1.0.21-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python36-rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpmconf/__pycache__/rpmconf.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc from install of python3-rpmconf-1.0.21-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python36-rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpmconf/__pycache__/rpmconf.cpython-36.pyc from install of python3-rpmconf-1.0.21-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python36-rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man3/rpmconf.3.gz from install of python3-rpmconf-1.0.21-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python36-rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.7 from install of libwebp-1.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libwebp7-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libwebpdecoder.so.3 from install of libwebp-1.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libwebp7-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libwebpdemux.so.2 from install of libwebp-1.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libwebp7-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libwebpmux.so.3 from install of libwebp-1.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libwebp7-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no support for upgrading from Centos 7 to Centos 8.

You can keep removing packages until it works but you’ll end up with a broken system in the end.